# Getting an element of a CCK field to use and modify in hook_form after_build

Tags: 6, hooks, forms

I have a partially working solution for using `hook_form after_build` on a CCK field. The field has various elements (it's created with a custom module but I don't want to modify that so I've created a small overrides module to do some trivial form alter stuff.) I've been at this a good part of the day and finally had some luck adding some simple text to the field so I am know I'm getting close.

In the main module, the CCK field has various elements. Once such element is:

```
$element['week_night'] = array(
    '#type'          => 'textfield',
    '#title'         => t('Week Night'),
    '#default_value' => isset( $element['#value']['week_night'] ) ? $element['#value']['week_night'] : NULL,
    '#attributes'    => array( 'class' => 'rate-widget-rate-field' )
  );
```

I am targeting the field itself in my overrides module as such:

```
<?php 
function rates_override_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  //drupal_set_message($form_id);
  //dsm($form);
  if($form_id == 'ldisilink_property_node_form'){
    $form['#after_build'][] = '_rates_override_after_build';
  }
}

function _rates_override_after_build($form, &$form_state) {
  // This works so we know we are good to this point:
  $form['field_rates']['#prefix'] = 'do stuff';
  // Now we want to change the label on week_night but it's not working. 
   $week_night = $element['week_night'];
   $form['field_rates'][$week_night]['#title'] = 'My new label title';
  return $form;
}
```

What I am trying to do is alter the label for the element `week_night`.  Using `dsm($form)` I've tried various combinations of:

```
   $week_night = $element['week_night'];
   $form['field_rates'][$week_night]['#title'] = 'My new label title';
```

... but it's not working yet, but I think I'm close.

Comment: where/how are you setting $element in your _rates_override_after_build() function?

Comment: @Jimajamma -- ah yes, it would appear I need to set the $elements variable. I just could not find any documentation on that part of CCK.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track. You want to set the **#title** attribute of the form element whose label you want to change, which can all be done at the hook_form_alter() time.

In order to change the label of the 'week_night' form element, try something like this:

```
function rates_override_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if($form_id == 'ldisilink_property_node_form') {
    $form['field_rates']['week_night']['#title'] = t('My new label');
}
```

This is assuming the 'week_night' form element is nested within 'field_rates' fieldset. If that is not the case, use:

```
$form['week_night']['#title'] = t('My new label');
```

instead.